# Linux Single Fork Daemon. How to reacquire a controlling terminal?

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, daemon, systems-programming

Everyone says that daemon should not have a controlling terminal.
And double-fork method is the correct way that a double-forked daemon will never acquire a controlling terminal since it's not a session leader.

However, if we create a single fork daemon with using setsid(), close all fds, redirect fd 0~2 to /dev/null, but still the daemon is a session leader.

Then how can it reacquire a controlling terminal? What can i do in order to see it?
I just want to test it really acquires a controlling terminal or not.

When i used ioctl and TIOCSCTTY, it never succeeds since there is no any valid fd to pass as a parameter.

Comment: I guess it would need to open a terminal device, like *getty* does.